# What is the most idiomatic way to unbound a reference in Rust?

Tags: rust

I need to return multiple mutable references to different elements of a data structure. Because the compiler can't check my logic that the references don't alias, I have to use unsafe code to unbound my references so that they can be cast to the correct return lifetime.

So far, the best solution I've discovered is, in an `unsafe` block:

- Casting the reference to a raw pointer
- Dereference the pointer and immediately take a mutable reference to the result.

```
struct Node<T> {
    item: T,
    next: NodeRef<T>,
}


type NodeRef<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

pub struct ListIterMut<'a, T> {
    cur: &'a mut NodeRef<T>
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for ListIterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let cur = unsafe {&mut *(self.cur as *mut NodeRef<T>)}; // Super ugly!
        cur.as_mut().map(|node| {
            self.cur = &mut node.next;
            &mut node.item
        })
    }
}
```

I have been shown more correct ways of solving this issue, where there is no need for `unsafe` at all, but regardless--in some case where you do have to unbound a reference, is there a more clean way of doing so than the method I described above? Or was it intentionally made clunky to discourage programmers from doing it?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e9212045865e02eacbdd6df0e0e7c9a9

Comment: That is a much more elegant design, thank you.

Comment: @Stargateur  I am still confused as to how this doesn't cause the same lifetime errors that my design produced (that show up if you take away the pointer casting).

Comment: all is on the Option, we `take` it from `self` so self is free to be mutate because cur is no longer bound to self lifetime. This is an advanced lifetime thing, like always why newbie in rust always want to implement linked list, Rust is not build to make your life easy with linked list. You start by the nightmare mode of Rust here

Comment: @PeterHall Let's just close as dup; I need to start have a dup list for linked list :p

Comment: @Stargateur Linked list was just an example though. I really appreciate your help with the design, but my question about unbounding references still stands.